Error on Step #2 deploying NextJs to Firebase App Hosting
I have a NextJs app and am trying to make the first deploy to Firebase App Hosting.
I followed their docs to setup the backend, and integrated with GitHub with auto-deploy enabled.
All of the builds fail with the same error:
2024-11-06 16:54:37.443 BRT
Step #2: Installing nextjs adaptor 14.0.9
2024-11-06 16:54:41.870 BRT
Step #2: === Node.js - Yarn (google.nodejs.yarn@2.1.0) ===
2024-11-06 16:54:41.871 BRT
Step #2: ***** CACHE MISS: "yarn_engine"
2024-11-06 16:54:41.871 BRT
Step #2: Installing Yarn v4.5.0
2024-11-06 16:54:41.872 BRT
Step #2: 2024/11/06 19:54:41 [DEBUG] GET https://repo.yarnpkg.com/4.5.0/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
2024-11-06 16:54:42.051 BRT
Step #2: Setting environment variable PATH=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_engine/bin:/layers/google.nodejs.runtime/node/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2024-11-06 16:54:42.070 BRT
Step #2: ***** CACHE MISS: "yarn_modules"
2024-11-06 16:54:42.072 BRT
Step #2: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-11-06 16:54:42.072 BRT
Step #2: Running "yarn install --non-interactive --prefer-offline --modules-folder=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules --frozen-lockfile --production=false (PATH=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_engine/bin:/layers/google.nodejs.runtime/node/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/.bin)"
2024-11-06 16:54:42.454 BRT
Step #2: Unknown Syntax Error: Invalid option name ("--modules-folder=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules").
2024-11-06 16:54:42.454 BRT
Step #2:
2024-11-06 16:54:42.454 BRT
Step #2: $ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--refresh-lockfile] [--check-cache] [--check-resolutions] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2: Done "yarn install --non-interactive --prefer-offline --modules-fo..." (418.675079ms)
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2: failed to build: (error ID: 7590068d):
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2: Unknown Syntax Error: Invalid option name ("--modules-folder=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules").
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2:
2024-11-06 16:54:42.489 BRT
Step #2: $ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--refresh-lockfile] [--check-cache] [--check-resolutions] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]
2024-11-06 16:54:42.491 BRT
Step #2: Timer: Builder ran for 7.35782479s and ended at 2024-11-06T19:54:42Z
2024-11-06 16:54:42.491 BRT
Step #2: ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
2024-11-06 16:54:43.694 BRT
Step #2: ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 51

This error is not in the Google Cloud Troubleshooting Docs and Gemini couldn't tell me what it's about either.
next.config.mjs
import bundleAnalyzer from '@next/bundle-analyzer';

const withBundleAnalyzer = bundleAnalyzer({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

export default withBundleAnalyzer({
  reactStrictMode: false,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ['@mantine/core', '@mantine/hooks'],
    serverActions: true,
    output: "export",
  },
});

firebase.json
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 3001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "venv",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "*.local"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}

